# Creating Excel named ranges does not work

Tags: excel, vb.net, named-ranges, excel-dna

I'm stuck here with a seemingly simple task. I'd like to create named ranges in Excel 2019 via Excel DNA on vb.net. I searched and tried every code example I could find but cannot reproduce their results. The debugger simply exits the function without throwing an error on the .names.add line.

The debug.prints all work fine, so my connection to Excel seems to work.

What am I missing here?

```
Imports MyDNA = ExcelDna.Integration
Imports MyXl = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Public Module Class1
    Public Function gaga()

        Dim MyApp As MyXl.Application = MyDNA.ExcelDnaUtil.Application
        Dim MyWb As MyXl.Workbook = MyApp.ActiveWorkbook
        Dim MySheet As MyXl.Worksheet = MyWb.ActiveSheet
        Dim myRange As MyXl.Range = MySheet.Cells(1, 1)

        Debug.Print(myRange.Column)
        Debug.Print(MyWb.Name)
        Debug.Print(MyWb.Names.Count)

        MyWb.Names.Add("Testt", myRange)

        Return 0

    End Function
End Module
```

Comment: Do you save the file?

Comment: Can you change your 'Function' to a 'Sub' and then run it by typing the name into the Alt+F8 'Run' dialog? I suspect you just can't create a Name inside a calculation context.